# How to rewrite an url without beening displayed the file extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How i rewrite url, using htaccess ,  i have tryed like this :

`RewriteRule ^file$ file.php [L]`

i don't want to be displayed the file extension

i want to rewrite url like this :

`http://example.com/file.php` into `http://example.com/file`

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^file$ /file.php
```